# Can I join a table with itself in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way that I can join a table with the same table?

Comment: Yes, but if you need more help you should provide an example (data and expected output)

Comment: Why should you need to join a table that you already selected? (bit curious)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explanation of self-joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458519/explanation-of-self-joins)

Answer (score 3):

## This is known as [Self Join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm).

Quoting [w3resource.com](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-self-join.php),

> A self join is a join in which a table is joined with itself (which is
> also called Unary relationships), specially when the table has a
> FOREIGN KEY which references its own PRIMARY KEY. To join a table
> itself means that each row of the table is combined with itself and
> with every other row of the table.
>
> The self join can be viewed as a join of two copies of the same table.
> The table is not actually copied, but SQL performs the command as
> though it were.

A typical example:

```
SELECT  a.ID, b.NAME, a.SALARY 
FROM CUSTOMERS a, CUSTOMERS b
WHERE a.SALARY < b.SALARY;
```

Comment: Isn't comma joins a bit outdated? I would always use a standard `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the self join.

An example to explain the self join. Lets say you have a table which have Employee and Supervisor details like this:

```
EmployeeName      SupervisorName
ABC                XYZ
DEF                YZX
PQR                XYZ
HJK                PQR
```

Now if I want to find who all employee have the same Supervisor as employee ABC.

So possible approach:

**Approach 1**

```
SELECT employeename
FROM employee
WHERE SupervisorName = "ABC"
```

So for this we need to have the name of the Supervisor for which we want to get the details(*An absurd one*)

**Approach 2:**

```
SELECT employeename
FROM employee
WHERE SupervisorName in
( SELECT SupervisorName 
FROM employee
WHERE employee_name = "ABC")
```

This one is not as efficient as using the Self Join

**Approach 3:- Using the Self Join**

```
SELECT e1.employeename
FROM employee e1 self join employee e2
on e1.SupervisorName  = e2.SupervisorName 
AND e2.employeename="ABC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you set an alias to the table

`... from my_table join my_table as 'othertable' ON ...`

Answer (score 0):

Following link describes self join in sql server : 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490%28v=sql.105%29.aspx