# SQL - How to put beside two records of the same table in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable

I have a table with this structure:

```
+------------+-----------------+----------+
| xreference |      title      | language |
+------------+-----------------+----------+
```

I want that to obtain something like this by means of an SQL query :

```
+------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
| xreference |   title_eng   |    title_ita    | language_eng | language_ita |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

how can i obtain this structure? There is a method that allow to organize two records of the same table in the same row?

For example, if i have this data:

```
+------------+-----------------+----------+
| xreference |      title      | language |
+------------+-----------------+----------+
|          1 | example_title   | eng      |
|          1 | example_title_2 | ita      |
+------------+-----------------+----------+
```

i want to obtain something like this:

```
+------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
| xreference |   title_eng   |    title_ita    | language_eng | language_ita |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
|          1 | example_title | example_title_2 | eng          | ita          |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I don't understand your table layout, could you try improving it by using [this](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a Self Join: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458519/explanation-of-self-joins

Comment: i re-build the table structure

Comment: And what if there's also a third language for an xreference?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way in your case is probably conditional aggregation:

```
select xreference,
       max(case when language = 'eng' then title end) as title_eng,
       max(case when language = 'ita' then title end) as title_ita,
       'eng' as language_eng, 'ita' as language_ita
from thisdata t
group by xreference;
```

I am not sure what the last two columns are supposed to be doing.

The advantage to this method over using a `join` is two-fold.  First, it is easy to add new languages.  And, this will show *all* `xreference` values, even those that have no translations in English and/or Italian.

Comment: I want all the values stored in my table not only max (or min or count). It is possible to perform this conditional aggregation without these operators?

Comment: @madmad, this will give you max of one value, i.e. the only value!

Comment: @madmad . . . This assumes that there is at most one English title and at most one Italian title for each `xreference`.  If this is not true, you might want `group_concat()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

do a self join but without the subselect:

```
SELECT t1.title as title_eng, t2.title as title_ita
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on (t2.xreference = t1.xreference)
where t1.language = 'eng' and t2.language = 'ita'
```

Comment: Just a comment, this will only return xreference's having both English and Italian languages. If one language is missing, nothing will be returned.

Comment: Of course. He can use the outer join depending on what he wants to obtain.

Comment: Too bad MySQL doesn't have full outer join.