# create columns from values in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a data in this format

```
employee_id date-time           activity
-------------------------------------------
23          01-06-2015 08:00    Punch In
23          01-06-2015 15:23    Punch Out
27          01-08-2015 08:12    Punch In
27          01-08-2015 14:13    Punch Out
```

I want this.

```
employee_id punch_in_time       punch_out_time
-------------------------------------------------
23          01-06-2015 08:00    01-06-2015 15:23
27          01-08-2015 08:12    01-08-2015 14:13
```

I want to write a view from the table to create the data format shown above. Can anyone help? Should I use a pivot?

Comment: Is it only one Punch In and one Punch Out per day?

Comment: yes, only one activity per day

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explanation of self-joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458519/explanation-of-self-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    employee_id,
    punch_in_time   = MIN(CASE WHEN activity = 'Punch In' THEN [date-time] END),
    punch_out_time  = MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'Punch Out' THEN [date-time] END)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY employee_id, CAST([date-time] AS DATE)
ORDER BY employee_id, punch_in_time
```