# Query to comapre scalar value of one table with all values of another column in same table

Tags: sql-server

for ex

```
empid  empname  mngrid
1         A       3
2         B       3
3         C       1
```

I want output tbl like below

```
empname mngrname
A          C
B          C
C          A
```

Comment: Google `JOIN` and you'll see a lot of tutorials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of self-joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458519/explanation-of-self-joins)

Comment: Please share sql query for this

Comment: Your hierarchy is actually a loop? Well that's an interesting company...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT A.empname, B.empname AS mngrname
FROM Your_Table A
LEFT JOIN You_Table B
ON A.mngrid = B.empid
```

Other case, you can use `OUTER APPLY`, like this:

```
SELECT A.empname, B.mngrname
FROM Your_Table A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT empname AS mngrname You_Table WHERE empid = A.mngrid) B
```