# SQL query which find different values on one column in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table where `Description` field had `scope = 10` and I inserted first row with `Description` = *`Cobra - Ni`* but a few days ago I realized that I need larger scope which was extended and proper value should be *`Cobra - Nisyor`*.

```
Column_ref     Description     Date          Money     Doc_nr
123            Cobra - Ni      06-11-2015    505.50    2000/10
123            Cobra - Toung   07-11-2015    505.50    2000/12
123            Cobra - Brain   07-11-2015    505.50    2000/25
123            Cobra - Nisyor  07-11-2015    505.50    2000/10
```

I need to write query which find first and last row from this exemplary table.

I tried in this way:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table as t1
WHERE t1.Description in
      (SELECT t2.Description
       FROM table as t2
       WHERE t1.Doc_nr = t2.Doc_nr
       AND t1.Description != t2.Description)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where is ordering column?

Comment: You specifically search for items that have a *different* description, and then you expect it to be the same?

Comment: I.e. when several rows for the same date, how do you chose first/last?

Comment: Are you looking for rows with the same doc_nr but different descriptions?

Comment: Based on your requirements and provided data: `WHERE Doc_nr = '2000/10'`

Comment: @Adish: Yes, I'm looking for rows with the same doc_nr but different description column

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff: I have more rows with this issues so I should use Doc_nr field in where clause.

Comment: What do you want to do after you get rows with same doc_nr and different descriptions?

Comment: In that case the delete solution provided by Michael McGriff will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming by "scope" you mean the *width of the column* was 10. Therefore you are looking to correlate rows, one having length = 10 and another starting with the same string and having length > 10. We can use the `LEN()` function to get the length of a character field, and `LEFT()` to get a substring - the latter of which we can use to compare the "new" with the "old".

For example:

```
with oldRows as (
    select *
    from myTable
    where LEN(Description) = 10
), newRows as (
    select *, LEFT(Description, 10) as oldKey
    from myTable
    where LEN(Description) > 10
)
select n.*, o.*
from oldRows o
join newRows n on o.Description = n.oldKey
-- Of course add any other comparisons you need to correlate rows:
--    and o.Column_ref = n.Column_ref
--    and o.[Date] = n.[Date]
--    and o.[Money] = n.[Money]
--    and o.Doc_nr = n.Doc_nr
```

For future reference you probably shouldn't have inserted additional new rows into the table after realizing the problem, and should have used an update instead.

Answer (score 0):

To find the rows you're looking for you need to do a [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458519/explanation-of-self-joins) on `doc_nr` including only those rows where the descriptions do not match, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d5eb/1).

```
CREATE TABLE basic
(
  column_ref INT,
  description VARCHAR(30),
  dateField DATETIME,
  amount DECIMAL(12,2),
  doc_nr VARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO basic (column_ref, description, dateField, amount, doc_nr)
VALUES (123, 'Cobra - Ni', '06/11/2015',505.50,'2000/10'),
       (123, 'Cobra - Toung', '07/11/2015',505.50,'2000/12'),
       (123, 'Cobra - Brain', '07/11/2015',505.50,'2000/25'),
       (123, 'Cobra - Nisyor', '07/11/2015',505.50,'2000/10');

SELECT *
FROM basic b
JOIN basic q ON b.doc_nr = q.doc_nr
WHERE b.description != q.description

╔════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════════════╦════════╦═════════╦════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════════════╦════════╦═════════╗
║ column_ref ║  description   ║       dateField        ║ amount ║ doc_nr  ║ column_ref ║  description   ║       dateField        ║ amount ║ doc_nr  ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════╬═════════╬════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║        123 ║ Cobra - Ni     ║ June, 11 2015 00:00:00 ║ 505.5  ║ 2000/10 ║        123 ║ Cobra - Nisyor ║ July, 11 2015 00:00:00 ║ 505.5  ║ 2000/10 ║
║        123 ║ Cobra - Nisyor ║ July, 11 2015 00:00:00 ║ 505.5  ║ 2000/10 ║        123 ║ Cobra - Ni     ║ June, 11 2015 00:00:00 ║ 505.5  ║ 2000/10 ║
╚════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════════════╩════════╩═════════╩════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════════════╩════════╩═════════╝
```

In order to actually `DELETE` the rows, replace the `SELECT` statement above with the following (provided you want to `DELETE` the rows which have the shorter description, your actual criteria may vary).

```
DELETE b 
FROM basic b
JOIN basic q ON b.doc_nr = q.doc_nr
WHERE LEN(b.description) < LEN(q.description);
```

Credit for the above syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server).

Comment: Your answer for sure is correct. I checked it on SQL Fiddle and it works. I suppose something is wrong with my data but i know that your solution is also correct.
Many thanks for SQL Fiddle, i didn't know this before!