# SQL - How to offset a table by 1 row

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would I join a table onto itself and offset the second table to shift up by 1 row?

I want to do this in order to calculate the amount of days until the next sale date.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is a [self-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458519/explanation-of-self-joins). We could answer better if you'd provide a sample of your table data, the results you'd like, and what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

If you have data recording sales, then you would get the next date using `lead()`:

```
select s.*,
       lead(saledate) over (partition by customerid order by saledate) as next_saledate
from sales s;
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly