# Transpose two rows into single row (mySql)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

in MySql I have this kind of table (datas):

[image]

What I want to do is to get date, temperature for sensor (1) , temperature for sensor (2) in a single row (group by date).

Now I have two records for the same dtg for sensor 1 and sensor 2...

Thank you

Comment: This also looks like you're using a DS18S20 on (I'm going to stab in the dark) a RPi.  I've just been doing the same thing, and have a bit of code for generating time-series data that might help you would like - https://gist.github.com/calcinai/801e4e805139cd18278e45c5da090340

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT dtg, GROUP_CONCAT(temperature ORDER BY sensor_id)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY dtg
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Ok but "group_concat" will concatenate two values separated by coma? is there a way to get atribute for each sensor? For example (dtg,temp1,temp2)?

Comment: `separated atribute for each sensor` ... what do you mean by this?

Comment: Now I have dtg atribute and (temp1,temp2) as single atribute.. what I want  is to get dtg,temp1,temp2  (if possible)

Comment: What you're talking about is transposing columns.  This isn't possible with mysql out of the box, but if you knew the `sensor_id`s beforehand, you can do things like `SELECT COALESCE(IF(sensor_id='x', temperature, NULL)) sensor_x, COALESCE(IF(sensor_id='y', temperature, NULL)) sensor_y`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458519/explanation-of-self-joins):

```
SELECT 
    a.dtg AS dtg1,
    a.sensor_id AS sensor_id1,
    a.temperature AS temperature1,
    b.sensor_id AS sensor_id2,
    b.temperature AS temperature2
FROM yourTable AS a
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS b 
    ON a.dtg = b.dtg
    AND NOT a.sensor_id = b.sensor_id
GROUP BY a.dtg
```

Comment: Kaii with your select statement I get duplicated values... http://s5.postimg.org/4mkm8my2v/screenshot_1236.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal hardcoding these values in the query, but this is a workaround to transpose the rows to columns:

```
SELECT dtg,
    COALESCE(IF(sensor_id='28-000004a9fa09', temperature, NULL)) t1, 
    COALESCE(IF(sensor_id='28-000004aa21cd', temperature, NULL)) t2
FROM readings
GROUP BY dtg
```

You might need to play with the aggregates if you start getting unpredictable time readings. Especially given the DB18B20s can sometimes take a while to read, it's possible you might get the seconds overlapping.