# SQL query to get the employee name and their manager name from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Employee table

```
Employee_id  Employee_name   Manager_id
-------------------------------------
Emp00001     Ram             Emp00005
Emp00002     Sharath         Emp00003
Emp00003     Nivas           Emp00005
Emp00004     Praveen         Emp00002
Emp00005     Maharaj         Emp00002
```

Output

```
Employee Name    Manager Name
------------------------------
Ram              Maharaj
Sharath          Nivas
Nivas            Maharaj
Praveen          Sharath
Maharaj          Sharath
```

In the `employee` table, there are three columns `Employee_id`, `employee_name` and `manager_id`. From the table, how to fetch the employee name and their manager name?

Comment: IS There any manager Table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of self-joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458519/explanation-of-self-joins)

Answer (score 13):

You can self-join the table to get the manager's name from his ID:

```
SELECT e.employee_name, m.employee_name AS manager_name
FROM   employee e
JOIN   employee m on e.manager_id = m.employee_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
SELECT employee_name AS Employee_Name,(SELECT employee_name FROM   employee  where
employeeid=ManagerID ) AS Manager_Name  FROM   employee
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Using below query you can get Employeename and ManagerName here i have only one table EmpMgr:
select e.employeename as ename ,e.managerid as mgrid , e1.employeename as managername from EmpMgr e join  EmpMgr e1 on e.managerid=e1.employeeid

Note : you can get all the employees name irrespective of manager name using the left join

select e.employeename as ename ,e.managerid as mgrid , e1.employeename as managername from EmpMgr e  left join  EmpMgr e1 on e.managerid=e1.employeeid

Answer (score 1):

Select * from employee

---

```
select e1.empname,e2.empname  as managername,e1.salary,
e1.mrg,e1.empno,e1.job,e2.mrg as BossMRG from employee e1
join
employee e2 on e1.mrg=e2.empno
left join 
employee e3 on e1.mrg=e3.empno and e3.job='manager' or e3.empno=e2.mrg
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Required table :- Employee.

## Query :-

```
SELECT e.Employee Name,
       e.Employee Name as Manager Name
  FROM Employee e JOIN Employee m 
    ON e.Employee id = m.Manager id
```

Explanation :-

By giving this condition "Employee e JOIN Employee m" it would automatically consider single table as two different table as "e" and "m" and then compare Employee id from table e to the manager id of table m.
whenever it find match that both the ID's are same that will get added to the result.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Friends**, Please check below solution.

This is result screenshot:
[image]

This is the query:

```
SELECT e.employee_name,m.Employee_name FROM   EmpTable e 
    INNER JOIN EmpTable m 
            ON M.Employee_id =e.manager_id
```

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully, manager table will be available in your DB

```
SELECT employee_name, M.manager_name
FROM   employee e
INNER JOIN tableManager M ON e.ManagerID = M.MangerID
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT e.ename,m.ename FROM   Emp e 
    INNER JOIN Emp m 
            ON M.EMPNO =e.mgr
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from the previous answers already posted?