# How to get name and manager name

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How to get name and manager name

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | name      | manager |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | bhupendra |       0 |
|  2 | shyam     |       1 |
|  3 | ram       |       1 |
|  4 | geeta     |       2 |
|  5 | sita      |       1 |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

i need result like

```
+-----------+-----------+
| name      | manager   |
+-----------+-----------+
| bhupendra |           |
| shyam     | bhupendra |
| ram       | bhupendra |
| geeta     | shyam     |
| sita      | bhupendra |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: what does your manager table look like? Or... does the manager ID relate to a row in that table?

Comment: Based on the example, the manager ID is just another row in that table.

Comment: i have only one table

Comment: +----+-----------+---------+
| id | name      | manager |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | bhupendra |       0 |
|  2 | shyam     |       1 |
|  3 | ram       |       1 |
|  4 | geeta     |       2 |
|  5 | sita      |       1 |
+----+-----------+---------+

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235524/sql-query-to-get-the-employee-name-and-their-manager-name-from-the-same-table/52235876#52235876

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the same table twice using alias

```
select a.name, b.name as manager 
from my_table a 
left join  my_table b on a.manager  = b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could self-join the `id` column on the `manager` column:

```
SELECT    e.name AS name, m.name AS manager
FROM      employee e
LEFT JOIN employee m ON m.id = e.manager
```

Comment: this is valid for only 2 level

Comment: @Simonare that's the output the OP wants - see the expected output in the question.

Comment: i have only one table

Comment: @BhupendraDudhwal This si a self-join - the `from` clause and the `left join` clause use the same table.

Comment: @BhupendraDudhwal care to share it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
with recursive cte (id, name, parent_id) as (
  select     id,
             name,
             manager
  from       employee
  union all
  select     p.id,
             p.name,
             p.manager
  from       employee e
  inner join cte
          on p.manager = cte.id
)
select * from cte;
```