# Postgre SQL: Add a column that is a level above the related column

Tags: sql, postgresql

The situation is this:
I have two columns in my database.

| User | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| Amy K. | Theo K. |
| Lena K. | Theo K. |
| Jiha L. | John L. |
| John L. | Victor L. |
| Theo K. | Simba K. |
| Simba K. | Ellen K. |

Now I need to make another column using PostgreSQL called Grandparent where I need to put users from the User column in the Grandparent column if they are Parents of the people in the Parent column. So it would look like this:

| User | Parent | Grandparent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amy K. | Theo K. | Simba K. |
| Lena K. | Theo K. | Simba K. |
| Jiha L. | John L. | Victor L. |
| John L. | Victor L. | null |
| Theo K. | Simba K. | Ellen K. |
| Simba K. | Ellen K. | null |

I need to do it directly from the database using SQL and save data in Power BI.

Comment: You can try checking for solutions involving [recursive queries](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-recursive-query/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can self-join your table using `LEFT JOIN` to get grandparent (null if not exists).

This query fetches the grandparent from the table by joining it with itself twice. The table is aliased as *p* (for Parent), and *gp* (for Grandparent). The `LEFT JOIN` statements connect Parent to Grandparent based on column Parent from first alias and User from second alias :

```
SELECT p.User_name, p.Parent, gp.Parent AS Grandparent 
FROM mytable p
LEFT JOIN mytable gp on p.Parent = gp.User_name
```

Results :

```
user_name   parent      grandparent
Amy K.      Theo K.     Simba K.
Lena K.     Theo K.     Simba K.
Jiha L.     John L.     Victor L.
John L.     Victor L.   null
Theo K.     Simba K.    Ellen K.
Simba K.    Ellen K.    null
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/chZcQCFf)

Comment: My query is slightly different from yours because I used `LEFT JOIN` to get the ones that are not matched as well, and I have included additional clarification to help understand the logic.

Comment: Ohh yea, LEFT JOIN is the better option.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

The table should be **self-joined**:

```
SELECT t.User, t.Parent, th.Parent AS Grandparent

FROM   table t

LEFT JOIN   table th on t.Parent = th.User
```

Link as a reference:
[SQL query to get the employee name and their manager name from the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235524/sql-query-to-get-the-employee-name-and-their-manager-name-from-the-same-table)