# MySQL to refer to row from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `tblMitigation`, which has several columns:

Headcode, Time, Origin, Destination, Mitigation, Next Service.

The `Next Service` column refers to another `Headcode` value in the same table. How can I use MySQL to look up the `Mitigation` column for that other service?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Do you have an example ?

Comment: You mean like a self join? You can join `tblMitigation` with `tblMitigation` but you should remember to put good aliases to avoid confusion

Comment: Has `tblmitigation.headcode` unique values, or is it possible that multiple rows have the same value?

Comment: @ChrisCordner Hello Chris. I could see in your history, that you did not accept an answer yet. If one of the answers below answer your question please accept it. [How to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is SELF JOIN and when would you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it) and al so [Explanation of self joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458519/explanation-of-self-joins)

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Good advice, unfortunate it is dupe and most likely will get closed because of that

Answer (score 1):

You could `JOIN` the table to itself. Use a `LEFT JOIN` in case there is no `Next Service` as yet. The `COALESCE` will ensure the value of `Next_Mitigation` is something different in that case e.g. `N/A`

```
SELECT current.*, COALESCE(next.Mitigation, 'N/A') AS Next_Mitigation
FROM tblMitigation current
LEFT JOIN tblMitigation next ON next.Headcode = current.`Next Service`
```